# Loop inserting worksheet name in column - mismatch error

Tags: vba, database, loops, mismatch

> Trying to do the following
>
> 1- Open directory with multiple workbooks (Origins), copy/paste
> each worksheet into Master workbook (Destin)
>
> 2- insert in Columns 'A' in Master worksheet (Destin) with the name of each worksheet from dir (Origin) - the worksheets name contain the date
>
> 3- Finally, consolidate all worksheets in Master workbook (Destin) into 'Summary' sheet by copy/paste each
> worksheet below the other (i.e. database format)
>
> got step-1 to work....stuck now (step-2 mismatch error)

```
Option Explicit

Sub AllFiles()

'Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Dim folderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NewSht As Worksheet
Dim FindRng As Range
Dim PasteRow As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

    
' set master workbook
Set Masterwb = Workbooks("masterbook_AAFC.xlsm")
folderPath = "C:\Users\axchilmeran.G3NETWORK\Downloads\Master_AAFC\" 'contains folder path

If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath & "\"

    Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.csv*")

        Do While Filename <> ""
    
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename)
            If Len(wb.Name) > 35 Then
                MsgBox "Sheet's name can be up to 31 characters long, shorten the Excel file name"
                wb.Close False
                GoTo Exit_Loop
            Else
                ' add a new sheet with the file's name (remove the extension)
                Set NewSht = Masterwb.Worksheets.Add(After:=Masterwb.Worksheets(1))
                NewSht.Name = Replace(wb.Name, ".pdf.csv", "")
                
                End If


' loop through all sheets in opened wb
For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        ' get the first empty row in the new sheet
    Set FindRng = NewSht.Cells.Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

        If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' If find is successful
                PasteRow = FindRng.Row + 1
            Else ' find was unsuccessfull > new empty sheet, should paste at the first row
                PasteRow = 1
        End If
            
    sh.UsedRange.Copy
    
    NewSht.Range("B" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

> these 2 lines below giving me mismatch error!

```
    **lastrow = NewSht.UsedRange.Rows(NewSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    Worksheets(NewSht).Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Value = NewSht.Name**
        
        
    Next sh
    
    wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
    wb.Close False

Exit_Loop:
    Set wb = Nothing
    Filename = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: you have 2 lines specified. which one errors? what is the value of `lastrow` when it errors? also, `NewSht.Range(` instead, since `NewSht` is already a worksheet object, and not a string.

Comment: value of lastrow = 46, the line after with Worksheets(NewSht).Range("A2:A" ... is giving mismatch error. thoughts?

Comment: did you read the end of my comment?

Comment: it worked! thank you braX! 
is there a clean way to do task-3 ?

Comment: There are plenty of questions about how to do task 3, there are many different ways, depending on your situation.